# Tomato leaves look... off with lightly yellowing leaves

Tags: tomatoes

We have some tomatoes which look... off, slightly yellowing leaves.

Is there anything we can do differently here? Or anything really obvious?

These plants have more or less lived under grow lights for a while. They were transplanted recently, too.

[image][image]

Comment: All plants we humans try to grow will need fertilizer.  Chemistry they can use for photosynthesis to make their own food for energy, repairs, growth and storage.  Save the Epsom salts for experts. Your plants need a little...balanced...fertilizer; NPK; nitrogen phosphorus and potassium.  Start with that.  Did you transplant these starts from indoors directly to the out door garden?  To real sunshine?  Big no no unless acclimated.  Get Osmocote 14-14-14 extended release fertilizer beads.  Safest bet for newbies!  Tell us more about your conditions and we will be able to recommend others.

Comment: If these tomatoes aren't in the garden soil yet, we need to talk before you transplant.  If they are in pots, they should be in potting soil as well as given a balanced fertilizer.

Comment: @stormy they were transplanted into pots that are now in our sunroom, so not outdoors without acclimiation.

Comment: Good...just to make sure, however, plants going from the out of doors to the indoors environment also need acclimatization.  Just need fertilizer...keep the Nitrogen in the formula LOWER than the P and the K or equal numbers.  I just got some Dr. Earth 5-5-5 All Purpose while standing in the grocery store line...follow the directions.  Did you use potting soil? I hope?  This plant needs fertilizer, it isn't able to make its own food via photosynthesis.  That will make a huge difference within days.

Comment: @stormy yup potting soil when we transplanted from seed starter soil!

Comment: Yay!! A little fertilizer and you'll have tomatoes in your sun room if there is enough light...You had artificial lights right?  Later.  You will have to pollinate your own flowers, no big deal.  Sounds bad, huh.  https://video.search.yahoo.com/search/video?fr=mcafee&p=tomatoes+pollination#id=1&vid=953a74fe4d8b1318948db3f53661a560&action=click  I have never heard the one using an electric toothbrush??

Comment: @stormy well I will trim the blossoms at this point since they aren't super big and not going outside for almost a month ;) But yeah, should be fun.

Comment: Okay, you are planning to take them out of doors, yes?  And you know how to acclimate?  Start with 5 minutes one day, for a few days, then go to 10 minutes for a few days...etc.?  DO NOT TRIM the blossoms.  Those are tomatoes.  Oh I would trim blossoms off in a heart beat if all I was concerned with was a vegetatively lush plant to last more than one season. If you want tomatoes, do not cut the flowers off.  The other thing about tomatoes is that the fruit is pretty much shaded by the leaves of the tomato, very important out of doors. Tomato production will continue the entire season.

Comment: When to Use Tomato Plant Fertilizers Tomatoes should be first fertilized when you plant them in the garden. You can then wait until they set fruit to start fertilizing again. After the tomato plants start growing fruit, add light fertilizer once every one to two weeks until the first frost kills the plant.

Read more at Gardening Know How: Fertilizing Tomatoes: Tips For Using Tomato Plant Fertilizer https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/tomato/tomato-fertilizer.htm  Also links to pruning in this article.

Answer (score 4):

It could just be the new soil and growing conditions, but it looks like magnesium deficiency, since the leaf is yellowing with darker veins, as I've read happens with magnesium deficiency. You might give the plant some Epsom salt (magnesium sulfate).

Comment: or just a generic fertilizer.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely exhausted the micronutrients in the potting soil you're using.  Potted plants are entirely reliant on external fertiliser use since they don't have access to the soil.  The early interveinal chlorosis that you're seeing could be magnesium, manganese etc.  And you don't know what deficiency is going to appear next.  So, better to give a general purpose fertilizer such as Miracle-gro that contains micronutrients and not just NPK.

http://www.haifa-group.com/knowledge_center/crop_guides/tomato/plant_nutrition/nutrient_deficiency_symptoms